# Find duplicate blocks of code in a Python file

Tags: python, lint, pylint, flake8, software-quality

is there a way to get warnings for duplicate blocks/lines of code in the same file for Python using pylint or flake8?

I am aware that for pylint [R0801](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/checkers/features.html#similarities-checker-messages) warns of duplicate code in different files, but I'd also like to get a warning if there is a significant (i.e. > 3 consecutive lines) code duplication within the same file.
For Flake8 I was not able to find that functionality at all (maybe through a plugin?)

Edit: need this for GitLab CI/CD integration, so functionality in an IDE like PyCharm is not an option.

Comment: asking for tool suggestions on SO is off topic as it tends to encourage spammy answers

Comment: removed asked for tool - any constructive comment?

Comment: it's still "suggest me a tool" as the answer is "no unless you use $x plugin"

Comment: more like a "how do I use the tool correctly"

Comment: neither tool in your question supports what you want out of the box without installing plugins (for which there are many choices)

Comment: would be more constructive if you would give an example, as I obviously did not find one, instead of holding back knowledge

Comment: that would be advertisery / spammy -- the entire reason it's off topic on SO.  I'd rather not get my comment / answer / account flagged

Answer (score 0):

Finding duplicate code within the same Python file is supported by a static code analysers, such as [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), Flake8, and mypy.

[Here is more info about this feature in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/analyzing-duplicates.html).

[image: PyCharm duplicate code detection]

Comment: As I want to use this in GitLab, Pycharm is not an option. Pylint only finds duplicate code in different files. flake8 I did not see that it finds duplicate code (if it does, please point me to it) - mypy I did not check yet.

Comment: Did you check [PyLint's documentation about "similarities"](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#similarities-options)

Comment: actually yes, that's where the R0801 comes from - but could not make it work on a single file - only between two files.